# Request tag synonyms Awk and Gawk

Tags: support, synonym-request

Recommending `[AWK]` and `[GAWK]` as synonyms.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gawk

> gawk (short for GNU awk) is a free implementation of awk.

**Edit:** So the question is more a matter of updating the description to identify that Gawk is sufficiently different from Awk.

[Can someone update the Gawk tag to reflect differences between Gawk and Awk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157772/can-someone-update-the-gawk-tag-to-reflect-differences-between-gawk-and-awk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every once and a while you see people working with busybox awk or some other rare system that does not have GNU awk, and it is important to not assume that they have the GNU version (which is much more capable).

Likewise, because the GNU implementation *is* much more powerful than the traditional and POSIX implementations it is useful for users to be able to note that they have it.

So, I'm against.